# BrowserRouter Doesn't work after deploying app on Apache24 (Windows)

Tags: reactjs, apache, deployment

BrowserRouter does not work after deploying to Apache24 on windows OS. I have made changes after referring to these [`post`](https://sanjeev-pandey.medium.com/hosting-reactjs-app-as-static-site-on-centos-using-apache-7c9e6d25a206) but did not work.

My App.js

```
<div className="App"> 
      <BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true} >
      <Route exact path="/coconad" component={Layout} /> 
           <Route exact path="/coconad/ContactUs" component={ContactUsForm} />
           <Route exact path="/coconad/Aboutus" component={Aboutus} />
        </BrowserRouter>
    
         </div>
```

My .htaccess (file with in build directory - httpd/coconad)

```
FallbackResource /index.js
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  
  RewriteEngine On
  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
  </IfModule>
```

My httpd.conf (c:/apache24/conf)

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">

    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "coconad",
  "homepage": "coconad",
  "version": "0.1.0",
```

I have 3 links in footer.js

```
 <table align="center" class="ant-table"> 
        <tr>
            <td class="footerSpanLink"><Link to="/coconad"> Home </Link></td>
            <td class="footerSpanLink"><Link to="/coconad/ContactUs">ContactUs</Link></td>
            <td class="footerSpanLink"><Link to="/coconad/Aboutus">About Us</Link></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is my Layout.js (am having all my header, footer and home pages references here)

```
import React from "react"
import Header from "./Header/Header"
import Footer from "./Footer/Footer"
import Home from "./Home/Home"
import "./../../index.css";
class Layout extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <>
        <Header /><br/>
        <Home />
        <main>{this.props.children}</main>
        <Footer />
      </>
    )
  }
}
export default Layout;
```

I have tried to deploy this React app on Apache24. It works in my localhost:3000 with npm start.
But when I deploy to apache webserver except for the homepage, am getting 404 errors.
Says http://localhost/coconad/ContactUs URL does not found

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I have resolved this issue after doing SO MANY combinations.. :-)
I first I moved everything to root folder (httpd) but thats okay. I just added one line to .htaccess file in the beginning, which was there already but I removed.

FallbackResource /index.js - was there which I removed it. Later I added the following line
FallbackResource /index.html

Comment: .htaccess file contents 

`FallbackResource /index.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>`